# Err1242 - sub query returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, scripting, subquery

What could be wrong with this script? 
I am getting the error

"[Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row".

How to fix this? Thank you!

```
    SELECT
  j.id AS JobID,
        CASE WHEN j.id = (SELECT o.attachment_id from origins o where o.attachment_type="Job" AND o.alliance_partner_id = 12) then "Channel 1"
        WHEN j.id = (SELECT o.attachment_id from origins o where o.attachment_type="Job" AND o.alliance_partner_id = 15) then "Channel 2"
        WHEN j.id = (SELECT t.record_id FROM tracked_records t where t.record_type = 'Job') then "Channel 3"
        WHEN j.id = (SELECT r.job_id from job_referrers r where r.url IN ('ios','android')) then "Channel 4"
        END AS "Channels"
FROM jobs j
GROUP BY j.id
;
```

Comment: This error message is self-explanatory.  Can you modify the sub selects so that they return only one record?

Answer (score 0):

One option to syntactically fix your query would be to use `WHERE IN` for each of the sub-`SELECT`s:

```
SELECT j.id AS JobID,
    CASE WHEN j.id IN (SELECT o.attachment_id from origins o where o.attachment_type="Job" AND o.alliance_partner_id = 12) THEN "Channel 1"
         WHEN j.id IN (SELECT o.attachment_id from origins o where o.attachment_type="Job" AND o.alliance_partner_id = 15) THEN "Channel 2"
         WHEN j.id IN (SELECT t.record_id FROM tracked_records t where t.record_type = 'Job') THEN "Channel 3"
         WHEN j.id IN (SELECT r.job_id from job_referrers r where r.url IN ('ios','android')) THEN "Channel 4"
    END AS "Channels"
FROM jobs j
GROUP BY j.id
```

Note that while this may get the query running, it might not logically be what you had originally intended.  So you should rexamine what you are trying to achieve here.